# How would you translate "The Adorned" for use as a collective title?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, word-request

I took a few years of Latin back in high school, but my understanding of the language never really surpassed novice levels.

I've been brainstorming names for a wolf pack in a story of mine; a lot of my early writing occurred while I was taking Latin, so much of this pack's naming and lore is influenced by Latin and the Roman Empire. The story has grown and changed over the years, and I've found that the pack's old name no longer fits them.

Currently, the pack is set apart by the radio collars many individuals wear. I'd like to rename the pack The Adorned, in reference to these collars that the wolves view as akin to religious vestments. I'd like to keep the pack's name in Latin to match linguistically with other titles used in their culture.

According to a few online dictionaries, it seems like "ōrnō, ōrnāre, ōrnāvī, ōrnātum" might be best for my meaning (if you've got a better suggestion, I'm all ears!) I vaguely remember lessons on gerunds and gerundives from my school days, but don't know if either of those classifications apply here. I'm also unsure of whether or not this title would require the use of a demonstrative like "ille." If anyone can help with usage and translation, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 10):

Cicero uses a participle of *orno* that could work as a substantive for you:

> sepulcrum floribus ornatum, Cic. Fl. 38, 95.

To make it plural, you could use *ornati (m), ornatae (f), ornata (n)*. Convention would dictate using the masculine to describe a group of males and females, so if it was me I would use *ornati*. I'm not sure if "The Ornati" has the feel you are going for, but it's one option to describe a group of adorned wolves or people.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help! Ornati sounds like what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Coyoteskip given that your English idea is "adorned," you could also say *adornati*.